# iPhone: How to send a HTTP request to a web service using Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, http

How to send a HTTP request to a web service using Objective-C ? I need to fetch some data from my MySQL DB, so I need to send the request so I could fetch the data.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Edit, because this is a popular question and time keeps going on. 
In the meantime Apple introduced NSJSONSerialization. Have a look a the docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization
Only if you need to create code for iOS earlier than 5.0 you may want to use the json-framwork as mentioned below.

Besides that, the following original answer is still valid:

Assuming that you exchange your data in JSON, you may be interested in reading this. 
http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/json-framework-for-iphone-part-2.html

However, the first part of that article answers your more general question on how to receive data from a web server/service:

```
- (NSString *)stringWithUrl:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
                                                    timeoutInterval:30];
        // Fetch the JSON response
    NSData *urlData;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;

    // Make synchronous request
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                        returningResponse:&response
                                                    error:&error];

    // Construct a String around the Data from the response
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

This is a simple example of a http request and surely good enough for your next steps. 
This method is given a URL and it returns the data sent by the server in an NSString.

Once that is working properly you will like to avoid that your app freezes while the request is "on the air". 
You can fix that by asynchronous requests. Google or the search on stackoverflow will provide you with links to examples and tutorials about that. But I suggest to go from here first, although this may not be the final solution.

Comment: Are you aware of any video tutorials of this example?

Comment: Frankly, I do not believe in video tutorials. They are time consuming, you cannot cut&paste samples or links and it is hard -and again time consuming- to refer back to certain parts of them. Sorry, I don't know any.

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways, but perhaps the easiest is to use an existing framework, ASIHTTPRequest.

See: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest has been "discontinued" by it's author. I think a lot of people are using AFNetworking now... Or just use NSURLConnection

Comment: STHTTPRequest looks like another good alternative. Very lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

Following is a lot of very famous library you can use for request

ASIHTTPRequest

AFNetwork

MFNetwork

You can search it in google, download in github or, yes, of course, why don't use Cocoapods. that's the best thing when i compare objective-c with other language.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

ASIHTTPRequest is a great and simple framework, so I second the recommendations from other posts. To be complete though, you should also know that you can do this natively in Objective-C without another framework. Look at the Apple documentation for the NSURLConnection and NSURLConnectionRequest classes for background.